# Main to sub panel

Tags: electrical

Okay, I have a 200amp main panel with 2 hots and 1 bare wire connected to a bonded neutral and ground bar. I'm trying to run a sub panel off this and the new panel has 2 hots a neutral and a bare ground in panel. How do I connect the sub panel when I only have 3 wires? I do have the ground bar and neutral separated in sub panel. And should I use a separate grounding rod on sub panel?

Comment: How did you come to have only 3 wires? Did you use metal conduit to connect the subpanel, and if so, which kind?

Comment: It was preexisting. I used 2/0 service cable

Comment: Are you saying that you used 3 wire cable for the run between the main and the sub, or that the cable coming into the main panel has only 3 wires in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main has neutral and ground bonded, so Hot-Neutral/Ground-Hot

Your subpanel has isolated Neutral and Ground, so Hot-Neutral-Hot **and** Ground.

The ground connects to the SAME BAR as Neutral at the Main Panel, but NOT at the Sub-Panel.

Your grounding conductor can be metallic (non-flexible) conduit, if it's continuous and correctly assembled all the way from the Main to the Sub. So it does not HAVE to be a wire, but it still needs to remain isolated everywhere but at the Main from Neutral. If you bought cable with only 3 conductors, you made a mistake and will need different cable, or conduit and wires.

If the Main is correctly grounded and the Sub is in the same building, there is no need for a Grounding Rod at the Sub-panel.

If the Sub-panel is in a separate building, a Grounding Rod (or other acceptable Grounding conductor, such as an Ufer ground aka "concrete encased electrode") is required local to *that* building *as well as* the separate Grounding conductor (which can be metal conduit, or a green or bare wire) that goes all the way to the Main panel.